# use XPColledtion with XPPageSelector

Tags: devexpress, xppageselector

When using XPCollection as the collection of XPPageSelector, does the XPCollection load all the objects that satisfy the specified criteria or just a page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XPCollection will contain a Page.